# VPN into one machine, then VPN to another from there

Tags: vpn

Is it possible to vpn into one machine and then vpn to another. Basically i want to be able to do something like

[Me]-----[Node1]-----[Node2]

where normally it would be:

[Me]-----[Node2]

So, i want Node2 to think i am Node1. Is this possible? Is there a way to do this? Reason being is i want to get from my computer to Node2, where Node2 has ip address filtering. Is there a way to do this at all, even if it's not vpn from [Me] to [Node1]. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: VPNCeption :-). Sure, why not. What technology are you using? Cisco Ipsec/PPTP?

Comment: @TiZon yea it's ipsec. Never heard of VPNCeption though.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the only way to do this is with VPN [split tunneling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split_tunneling) or site to site VPN hardware. Otherwise the virtual adapter will lock out an attempt for more than one NIC in node1.

You could also probably use node1 as a virtual host and RDP to a guest then tunnel to node2 with a soft client from the guest. It would be pretty amazing if you got it to work.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using VirtualBox to do as such, The Virtual Box guest OS is Windows 7, My main OS is using Win 7 too. What I did is, 1st I connect to my A VPN. Then I fire Up my VirtualBox to use the A VPN, after the guest OS load, the I fire Up the 2nd VPN. So I'm using the 2nd VPN through the guest OS. So I don't need to think about anything else than that. Basically I'm tunneling myself inside a tunnel. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

It's probably possible... in theory. Each VPN connection is an independent connection. When you VPN to Node 1 you're the client to Node 1. When Node 1 VPN's to Node 2 then Node 1 is the client to Node 2.

How this would work in a practical sense is another matter.